# I want to get data from service using retrofit, how can I achieve this in android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, retrofit

I have already crated my class models in my project thanks to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

The json below is the jsonArray I must get data from.

```
{
  "response": true,
  "timestamp": "23-11-2018 01:21:13",
  "status": 200,
  "data_response": {
    "responseCapaDigital": {
      "responseDescription": "Operación exitosa",
      "responseID": 1
    },
    "encabezadoResp": {
      "tscNum": "0",
      "tscAlfa": "Operación exitosa",
      "fechaRsp": "2018-11-23T01:21:12.878"
    },
    "codeResponseFI": "0000",
    "descriptionResponseFI": "Bancos obtenidos correctamente",
    "totalBanks": "1",
    "bankList": [
      {
        "bankCode": "421",
        "bankName": "GEM-HSBC2",
        "bankShortName": "421"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "GET BANK CATALOG"
}
```

The way this should work is when I send a BankCode for example "443" the service returns a Json array like the one above.

My connectionHanlder contains:

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic eE9IMC5JdlJaRFZaVTNkV05YazUwZHltVk9MTz"})
    @POST("catalog/getCatalogoBancos")
    Call<ResponseServiceModel> getCatalogoBancos(@Body String body);
```

My retrofitClient:

```
 public static final String BASE_URL = "http://my_ip:8484/v1/";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
final static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();


public static Retrofit getApi() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()))
                .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }};

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts,
                new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext
                .getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .hostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER).build();

        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

ResponseServiceModel:

```
@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Boolean response;
@SerializedName("timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("data_response")
@Expose
private DataResponse dataResponse;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;

public Boolean getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Boolean response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public DataResponse getDataResponse() {
    return dataResponse;
}

public void setDataResponse(DataResponse dataResponse) {
    this.dataResponse = dataResponse;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

DataResponse:

```
 @SerializedName("responseCapaDigital")
@Expose
private ResponseCapaDigital responseCapaDigital;
@SerializedName("encabezadoResp")
@Expose
private EncabezadoResp encabezadoResp;
@SerializedName("codeResponseFI")
@Expose
private String codeResponseFI;
@SerializedName("descriptionResponseFI")
@Expose
private String descriptionResponseFI;
@SerializedName("totalBanks")
@Expose
private String totalBanks;
@SerializedName("bankList")
@Expose
private List<BankList> bankList;


public ResponseCapaDigital getResponseCapaDigital() {
    return responseCapaDigital;
}

public void setResponseCapaDigital(ResponseCapaDigital responseCapaDigital) {
    this.responseCapaDigital = responseCapaDigital;
}

public EncabezadoResp getEncabezadoResp() {
    return encabezadoResp;
}

public void setEncabezadoResp(EncabezadoResp encabezadoResp) {
    this.encabezadoResp = encabezadoResp;
}

public String getCodeResponseFI() {
    return codeResponseFI;
}

public void setCodeResponseFI(String codeResponseFI) {
    this.codeResponseFI = codeResponseFI;
}

public String getDescriptionResponseFI() {
    return descriptionResponseFI;
}

public void setDescriptionResponseFI(String descriptionResponseFI) {
    this.descriptionResponseFI = descriptionResponseFI;
}

public String getTotalBanks() {
    return totalBanks;
}

public void setTotalBanks(String totalBanks) {
    this.totalBanks = totalBanks;
}

public List<BankList> getBankList() {
    return bankList;
}

public void setBankList(List<BankList> bankList) {
    this.bankList = bankList;
}
```

EncabezadoResp:

```
 @SerializedName("tscNum")
@Expose
private String tscNum;
@SerializedName("tscAlfa")
@Expose
private String tscAlfa;
@SerializedName("fechaRsp")
@Expose
private String fechaRsp;

protected EncabezadoResp(Parcel in) {
    tscNum = in.readString();
    tscAlfa = in.readString();
    fechaRsp = in.readString();
}


public String getTscNum() {
    return tscNum;
}

public void setTscNum(String tscNum) {
    this.tscNum = tscNum;
}

public String getTscAlfa() {
    return tscAlfa;
}

public void setTscAlfa(String tscAlfa) {
    this.tscAlfa = tscAlfa;
}

public String getFechaRsp() {
    return fechaRsp;
}

public void setFechaRsp(String fechaRsp) {
    this.fechaRsp = fechaRsp;
}
```

ResponseCapaDigital:

```
 @SerializedName("responseDescription")
@Expose
private String responseDescription;
@SerializedName("responseID")
@Expose
private Integer responseID;

public String getResponseDescription() {
    return responseDescription;
}

public void setResponseDescription(String responseDescription) {
    this.responseDescription = responseDescription;
}

public Integer getResponseID() {
    return responseID;
}

public void setResponseID(Integer responseID) {
    this.responseID = responseID;
}
```

BankList:

```
  @SerializedName("bankCode")
@Expose
private String bankCode;
@SerializedName("bankName")
@Expose
private String bankName;
@SerializedName("bankShortName")
@Expose
private String bankShortName;



public String getBankCode() {
    return bankCode;
}

public void setBankCode(String bankCode) {
    this.bankCode = bankCode;
}

public String getBankName() {
    return bankName;
}

public void setBankName(String bankName) {
    this.bankName = bankName;
}

public String getBankShortName() {
    return bankShortName;
}

public void setBankShortName(String bankShortName) {
    this.bankShortName = bankShortName;
}
```

And finally the method I have inside my RequestMethods class where I do the call:

```
public void getBankNickName(final String bankId) {

    loadingDialog.show();
    JSONObject jsonCatalog = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonCatalog.put("bankId", bankId);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    responseService = conectionHandler.getCatalogoBancos(jsonCatalog.toString());
    responseService.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseServiceModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseServiceModel> call, Response<ResponseServiceModel> response) {
            Log.e("Catalog Code ", String.valueOf(response.code()));
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                ResponseServiceModel responseServiceModel = response.body();
                if (responseServiceModel.getResponse().equals(true)) {

                    Log.e("BankName",responseServiceModel.getDataResponse().getBankList().getBankName());

                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    responseError(response.body().getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                serverError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseServiceModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

When I call getBankNickName inside my RequestMethods class It prints my `Log "Catalog code"` but not `Log"BankName"`

I know it is a lot of code but I just can't figure it out!!! please help

Comment: I just Googled - "using retrofit in android tutorial" .... About 265,000 results ..

Comment: Yes, but not all the Json arrays are the same

Comment: I mean maybe you would like to try yourself and then post a question, with your retrofit code when if get stuck, rather than asking someone to do all the work for you without an attempt by yourself.  Maybe learning retrofit might be helpful in the future because, as you say, not all json arrays are the same ..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the [gson-converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson) from `mavenCentral()`, in order to consume `JSON`:

```
dependencies {
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
}
```

then use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), in order to create the required object mappings.